# Why isn't there more dark milk chocolate or "light" dark chocolate?

Tags: chocolate

My understanding is that the difference between dark chocolate and milk chocolate is that milk chocolate has milk solids and more sugar.

Why don't we often see chocolate with say 70% cocoa solids, 10% milk solids and 20% sugar?

Similarly why don't we see 30% cocoa solids, 70% sugar (no milk solids) for a light-dark chocolate?

Comment: Some cheap dark chocolate is close to your second suggestion but often has added fat. There's certainly 40% dark chocolate around but it seems very sweet.

Comment: Do you have some references or examples to back up your classifications?